# CSV data set config just working for 1 line

Tags: scripting, load, jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

I have recorded a script, in that script only a search id is changed after login and search a field

After recording i modified the script and i have provided a "CSV_Data Set COnfig" file to read a list of search ids.

The issue is

If i provide only one search id in that csv that is run correctly, but if i add multiple search ids in that file and run the script that number of time, only the first line run for that X number of times, but in Jmeter it shows that the URL of the search id was made correctly.

Can someone guide?

I have used loop controller too to run X number of times for that search ids, but same is the result.

How can i run that? (As i recorded the script 1 time and just modified that search id with csv)

The script is working fine for 1 search id, but not for multiple (after providing the search ids through csv file through csv data set config)

What i am doing wrong? please guide

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the csv and the loop controller at the same level.
You should put the csv data set configuration as a child of loop controller

```
*--thread Group
*----loopcontroler
*------csv
*------httpsampler
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, they are at the same level. Let me check them and inform you after following the guidelines mentioned by you :) Thanks for guiding